# What are the characteristics of the suffix ～びる?

Tags: words, suffixes, morphology

The word 大人びた is in common use in Japanese, but I noticed that I couldn't think of another use of ～びる apart from that. [EDICT](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=2409210) lists only 大人びた and 鄙びた.  [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8B-614131) lists 田舎びた and 古びる, although according to a Japanese friend of mine, the standard usage is 古びた.

**Question 1**: Is ～びる always in the past tense because it expresses a current state? Could it be used to describe a future possibility, i.e. using 大人びる to express that someone will become more grown up. `その子はどんどん大人びるだろう？？`

**Question 2**: Are there other words (apart from those listed above) which contain ～びた and are in common use in Japanese?

Comment: その、一つ目のリンク、開けないです（ERROR EXIT: Method not POSTって表示されます）。 「びる」は auxiliary でしょうか。。辞書には「接尾辞」"suffix" と書いてあるような・・

Comment: 指摘してくれてありがとうございました。リンクを直しました。：）

Comment: そおなんですよね・・　`［接尾］《動詞上一段型活用［文］ぶ（上二段型活用）》名詞または形容詞の語幹などに付いて...` って書いてありますね・・「～じみる」「～っぽい」とかも活用するけど接尾辞らしいです・・

Comment: ok I'll edit the title

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Is ～びる always in the past tense because it expresses a
>   current state?

No. When you use it in the position of the predicate, what is currently in that state is expressed like その子は大人びている. The same can be applied to modifying clauses like その大人びている子, but this time, you can rephrase it as その大人びた子 as well.

> Could it be used to describe a future possibility

Yes.

> Question 2: Are there other words (apart from those listed above)
>   which contain ～びた and are in common use in Japanese?

I don't come up with any besides ひなびた, 大人びた and 古びた.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to use it for a future possibility? Thanks.

Comment: @kan 「大人びてくるだろう」とかですかね・・・？